# Trying to have the corresponding answer by typing the room number

Tags: python, list, input, arguments, line

```
def main():
    # Initialize dictionaries
    rooms = { 'CS101':3004, 'CS102':4501, 'CS103':6755,
                        'NT110':1244, 'CM241':1411}
    
    instructors = {'CS101':'Haynes', 'CS102':'Alvarado',
                                 'CS103':'Rich', 'NT110':'Burke',
                                 'CM241':'Lee'}
    times = {'CS101':'8:00 am', 'CS102':'9:00 am',
                     'CS103':'10:00 am', 'NT110':'11:00 am',
                     'CM241':'12:00 pm'}
    course = input('Enter a course number:' )
    
    if course not in rooms:
        print(course, 'is an invalid course number.')
    else:
        print('The details for course', course, 'are:')
        print('Room:', rooms)
        print('Instructor:', instructors[course])
        print('Time:', times)

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Once I write the corresponding course number I should get the corresponding answer, instead I get everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are trying to print out the dictionary, you are not accessing the value and instead trying to print out the whole dictionary in some cases.

Here's how you can fix this:

```
def main():
    # Initialize dictionaries
    rooms = {'CS101': 3004, 'CS102': 4501, 'CS103': 6755, 'NT110': 1244, 'CM241': 1411}
    instructors = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', 'CS103': 'Rich', 'NT110': 'Burke', 'CM241': 'Lee'}
    times = {'CS101': '8:00 am', 'CS102': '9:00 am', 'CS103': '10:00 am', 'NT110': '11:00 am', 'CM241': '12:00 pm'}
    course = input('Enter a course number:')
    if course not in rooms:
        print(course, 'is an invalid course number.')
    else if course not in instructors:
        print(course, 'is an invalid course number.')
    else if course not in times:
        print(course, 'is an invalid course number.')
    else:
        print('The details for course', course, 'are:')
        print('Room:', rooms[course])
        print('Instructor:', instructors[course])
        print('Time:', times[course])


main()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this I get ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Can you tell me the input you were using?

Comment: I tried typing CS101

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem! I'll update my answer. Wait a moment :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can't believe I missed simple things like that.

Comment: No problemo, happens to everyone :)

Comment: This will be problematic if the course identifier entered exists in *rooms* but not in *instructors* or *times*

Comment: Fixed that problem!

Answer (score 3):

You have three dictionaries (you should really only have one due to the repetition of the course code). However, based on what you currently have you need ensure that the course code exists in all three dictionaries.

```
def main():
    # Initialize dictionaries
    rooms = { 'CS101':3004, 'CS102':4501, 'CS103':6755,
                        'NT110':1244, 'CM241':1411}
    
    instructors = {'CS101':'Haynes', 'CS102':'Alvarado',
                                 'CS103':'Rich', 'NT110':'Burke',
                                 'CM241':'Lee'}
    times = {'CS101':'8:00 am', 'CS102':'9:00 am',
                     'CS103':'10:00 am', 'NT110':'11:00 am',
                     'CM241':'12:00 pm'}
    course = input('Enter a course number: ' )
    
    if course in rooms and course in times and course in instructors:
        print('The details for course', course, 'are:')
        print('Room:', rooms[course])
        print('Instructor:', instructors[course])
        print('Time:', times[course])
    else:
        print('Invalid course')

# Call the main function.
main()
```

A better construct could be:

```
def main():
    courses = {'CS101': {'room': 3004, 'instructor': 'Haynes', 'time': '8:00 am'},
               'CS102': {'room': 4501, 'instructor': 'Alvarado', 'time': '9:00 am'},
               'CS103': {'room': 6755, 'instructor': 'Rich', 'time': '10:00 am'},
               'NT110': {'room': 1244, 'instructor': 'Burke', 'time': '11:00 am'},
               'CM241': {'room': 1411, 'instructor': 'Lee', 'time': '12:00 am'}}

    course = input('Enter a course number: ')

    if cd := courses.get(course):
        print('The details for course', course, 'are:')
        print('Room: {}\nInstructor: {}\nTime: {}'.format(*cd.values()))
    else:
        print('Invalid course')


# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: Just 8 sec gap @cobra posted smae ..HAhah

Comment: This should be a valid answers...because we are linking 3 different dict having same keys. It is neccessary to check before accessing them +1

Answer (score 0):

What stopping you replicate logic of `intsructor` as you done correctly. do same for rest.

```
def main():
    # Initialize dictionaries
    rooms = { 'CS101':3004, 'CS102':4501, 'CS103':6755,
                        'NT110':1244, 'CM241':1411}
    
    instructors = {'CS101':'Haynes', 'CS102':'Alvarado',
                                 'CS103':'Rich', 'NT110':'Burke',
                                 'CM241':'Lee'}
    times = {'CS101':'8:00 am', 'CS102':'9:00 am',
                     'CS103':'10:00 am', 'NT110':'11:00 am',
                     'CM241':'12:00 pm'}
    course = input('Enter a course number:' )
    
    if course not in rooms:
        print(course, 'is an invalid course number.')
    else:
        print('The details for course', course, 'are:')
        print('Room:', rooms[course])
        print('Instructor:', instructors[course])
        print('Time:', times[course])

# Call the main function.
main()
```

Sample outputs #

```
Enter a course number:CS101
The details for course CS101 are:
Room: 3004
Instructor: Haynes
Time: 8:00 am
```

Comment: You need to check all three dictionaries. The course id might exist in *rooms* but not in *instructors* or *times*